# _WIN32_WINNT Not defined

Tags: c++, ntdll

I had a problem with using `winternl.h`, I was using some of the datatypes out of there and have sucessfully compiled it for x64 without any problems. However I made some changes and now for some reason its failing to compile, through debugging I've found that the reason seems to be down to `_WIN32_WINNT` not being defined at all which causes `winternl.h` to not define any types. It was specifically this that was causing the problem with the `PEB` struct

```
EXTERN_C PEB* NTAPI RtlGetCurrentPeb(VOID);
```

Now the only thing I've seemingly changed is removing precompiled headers and creating a new class. Neither of which had the define for `_WIN32_WINNT`. I've created a brand new project copied the class that imported `winternl.h` over and compiled it fine. Everything is the same, imports, includes and libs etc. I can't get my head around what I did to cause this to not be defined. I've spent ages going over the two projects and cant find a cause for the problem.

I can upload the code to pastebin if need be however as both classes are the same in each project I shouldnt think this should make a difference. I guess I must of messed with something in the projects settings but I can't figure out what that may be

Comment: `_WIN32_WINNT` is supposed to be defined in your project settings

Comment: where would I be able to find that setting?

Comment: @Andy That was the answer, turns out I had a `#include <winternl.h>` in my dllmain.cpp without a windows include that was the culprit. Thanks this was stumping me for ages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_WIN32_WINNT` comes from the include file `<windows.h>`, so in order to fix the error you are seeing:

In the file throwing the error, change this:

```
#include <winternl.h>

// ...
```

to this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>

// ...
```